# Is it possible to read a csv with `\r\n` line terminators in pandas?

Tags: pandas, csv, python-3.9

I'm using `pandas==1.1.5` to read a CSV file. I'm running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

csv_kwargs = dict(
    delimiter="\t",
    lineterminator="\r\n",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
    escapechar="!",
)
pd.read_csv("...", **csv_kwargs)
```

It raises the following error: `ValueError: Only length-1 line terminators supported`.
Pandas documentation confirms that line terminators should be `length-1` (I suppose single character).

Is there any way to read this CSV with Pandas or should I read it some other way?
Note that the docs suggest `length-1` for C parsers, maybe I can plugin some other parser?

EDIT: Not specifying the line terminator raises a parse error in the middle of the file. Specifically `ParserError: Error tokenizing data.`, it expects the correct number of fields but gets too many.

EDIT2: I'm confident the kwargs above were used to created the csv file I'm trying to read.

Comment: Does the file not read correctly on your platform if you don't specify a line terminator? A lot of of those settings seem unnecessary and `escapechar='!'` seems plain weird...

Comment: @JonClements I updated the question. I don't know why the specific `escapechar` was chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be in the escapchar, since `!` is a common text character.

Python's csv module defines a [very strict use of escapechar](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.escapechar):

> A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is False.

but it's possible that [pandas interprets it differently](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> One-character string used to escape other characters.

It's possible that you have a row that contains something like:

```
...\t"some important text!"\t...
```

which would escape the quote character and continue parsing text into that column.

Comment: Remaking the csv without specifying the `escapechar` and reading with pandas without specifying the `lineterminator` seems to have solved the issue. I'll accept the answer, thx!